# Javascript - Remove space- not breaks

Tags: javascript, whitespace, paragraph

How can i remove space in a string, without removing the breaks inside?

```
$new=$new.replace(/\s+/g,' '); //not working correct


this       is a test.
please    remove only   the
Space not
the       breaks inside


this is a test.
please remove only the
Space not
the breaks
```

Comment: Why are you using `\s+`? Do you know what it means at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `/ +/g`:

```js
$new = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

$new = $new.replace(/ +/g,' ');
// or $new = $new.replace(/(\s(?=\s))+/g,'');
 
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = $new;
```

```html
<pre id="content">
this       is a test.
please    remove only   the
Space not
the       breaks inside
</pre>

<pre id="result">
</pre>
```

Comment: a better demo would be using a `pre` tag ;) http://jsbin.com/doheqi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Works, but using space in a regular Express is not ISO Conform

Comment: @dazzafact I tried another way, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m58fgvyo/) ISO conform?

Answer (score 1):

```
$new = $new.split(/ +/).join(' ');
```

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what was asked.

Comment: Cause you'll lose `newlines` (since the `s`) - Newlines are needed, the multiple spaces are not.

Comment: Now it just does nothing.

Comment: @Juhana: no, it doesn't. This is a very common javascript technique.

Comment: If you replace all spaces with equal number of spaces, you're left with the exact same string. Go ahead and try it.

Comment: @AlvinThompson please take a look : http://jsbin.com/doheqi/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Juhana: I meant your previous comment that it did the opposite of what the OP asked for.

Comment: Your previous code *did* the opposite of what was asked (removed the line breaks and left spaces untouched.)

Comment: @AlvinThompson what you want is probably this: `$new.split(/ +/).join(' ');` http://jsbin.com/doheqi/6/edit?html,js,output